# Functional equations with involutions

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

Having seen that the topic of functional equations is loved by StackExchange, I have constructed this problem hoping that it will please readers.

> Solve the functional equation
>   $$
>   [f(x)]^2f\left(\ln\left(\frac {e^x+1}{e^x-1}\right)\right)=ax
> $$
>   where $a$ is a positive constant and $x>0$.

**HINT:**

> Prove first that $g(x)= \ln\left(\frac {e^x+1}{e^x-1}\right)$ is an involution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not intended as a place to pose puzzles.

Comment: Politely, it might be interesting to know the border from which you call "puzzle" to a mathematical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\log\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^{x}-1}\right)$: $g$ maps $\mathbb{R}^+$ into $\mathbb{R}^+$, $g(g(x))=x$ and the only fixed point of $g$ is $x_0=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$. For any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+\setminus\{x_0\}$, let $y=g(x)$. We have to fulfill:

$$ f(x)^2\,f(y) = a x,\qquad f(x)\,f(y)^2 = a y $$
hence by dividing the first identity by the square root of the second one$^{(*)}$ we get:

$$ f(x)^{\frac{3}{2}} = \sqrt{a}\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}} $$
hence:
$$ f(x)^3 = \frac{a x^2}{y} = \frac{a x^2}{g(x)} $$
and:

> $$ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{ax^2}{\log\left(\frac{e^x+1}{e^{x}-1}\right)}}.$$

$^{(*)}$ $f$ is positive since $f(y)=\frac{ax}{f(x)^2}> 0$ gives $f(x)> 0$.

Comment: Note the title in  plural; then the g could be any involution (not very "irregular", of course) and the solution would be analogue .¿Am I wrong?.Regards.                                                                                     You need, maybe, take  natural logarithm ln and not log in order to have an involution?

Comment: @Ataulfo: I'd say that works for any involution of $\mathbb{R}^+$, you're right. Anyway I always write $\log$ by meaning the natural logarithm.

Comment: OK, however base 10 is useful too so a notation like $log_{10}$ could be unnecessary....Cheers.